# Dapper to DataTable

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a scenario where I need to return a `DataTable` from a query using Dapper.
How do I return a `DataTable` from a query using Dapper?

```
DataTable dt = connection.Query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

Comment: Dapper is not the correct tool for this job. As Vivek says, Dapper is designed to map directly to objects, not 'DataSet's.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There will be no advantage *whatsoever* in using dapper for a scenario involving `DataSet`. And in particular, your specific example (without any parameters etc) is so trivial (not meant negatively - simply objectively) that you might as well use `ExecuteReader` directly, or use a `DbDataAdapter`

I am, however, open to exposing an API on dapper that exposes the `IDataReader` API from dapper - you could feed that to any consumer you want, `DataSet` / `DataTable` included. But I really must question: what would be the *point* in performing this example via dapper? It might make more sense if you were at least using dapper to handle parameters (I'm damned pleased with how the parameter handling worked out, truth be told).

Answer (score 7):

Huh? Dapper only provides extension methods over ADO.NET – so that you don't have to deal with DataTables and DataSets!

If DataTables and DataSets are what you want – you can still use vanilla ADO.NET [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter) will give you all the DataTables your heart desires.

Comment: What I need is to feed a ReportViewer with data from a query Dapper.
How to do it with Dapper?

this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt = this.inputValuesTableAdapter.GetData();     

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt); 

this.reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource); 
this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();

Comment: @user2421145 did  you tried without ***Dapper*** ? any solution about it ?